# Docker CMD + ENTRYPOINT not matching command line behavior

Tags: java, docker, vert.x

I am trying to build a vertx docker environment based on a distroless java image. When I run the docker container, it won't find the class I am trying to execute.

However, when I run the command in the container it works just fine.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:debug
ADD vert.x-3.7.0.tar.gz /usr/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp", "'/usr/vertx/lib/*'", "io.vertx.core.Launcher", "version"]
CMD ["-start"]
```

When I run the container, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.vertx.core.Launcher
```

So I ran the image with the following command:

```
docker run --entrypoint=sh -ti <image_name>
```

which gives a busybox shell. I then entered the following on the command line:

```
java -cp '/usr/vertx/lib/*' io.vertx.core.Launcher version
```

And it worked fine, giving me the following output

```
Apr 07, 2019 7:20:18 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VersionCommand
INFO: 3.7.0
```

I expected the same behavior from the ENTRYPOINT + CMD combination. I just can't seem to figure out why that combo isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `CMD` line altogether?

Comment: I have, same behavior.

Comment: However, I have removed the CMD *and* the quotes (as described below). So removing the CMD may have contributed to getting it to work, but on it's own it did not solve the problem. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: glad you got it figured out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your `Dockerfile`.  You have:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp", "'/usr/vertx/lib/*'", "io.vertx.core.Launcher", "version"]
```

There are too many quotes in the third parameter.  You have:

```
"'/usr/vertx/lib/*'"
```

You want:

```
"/usr/vertx/lib/*"
```

In your current `Dockerfile`, the argument to the `-cp` option is the literal value `'/usr/vertx/lib/*'`, including the single quotes. This of course does not match any filesystem path.

Comment: Thanks much. I thought that I had tried this already but evidently not. And I thought since the single quotes worked on the command line, it would work. Again, evidently not :) Thank you again, this is good to go!

Comment: The behavior here is pretty much identical to the command line: you would have the same problem in the shell if you were to run `java -cp "'/usr/vertx/lib/*'" io.vertx.core.Launcher version`.

Comment: right, but I would think that only the single quotes would make it to the command line. For example, the parameter "io.vertx.core.Launcher" is treated as io.vertx.core.Launcher on the command line, right? So I assumed that "'/usr/vertx/lib/*'" would make it to the command line as '/usr/vertx/lib/*', which works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Final solution was to use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/java
ADD vert.x-3.7.0.tar.gz /usr/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp", "/usr/vertx/lib/*", "io.vertx.core.Launcher", "version"]
```

I removed the :debug only because the busybox shell was only for debugging. It did not affect the solution.

Final size was 222MB, down from about 474MB! I'll have to do some testing to see how fully functional the image is, but as of right now I am hopeful that this will function as a slimmed down vertx image.

Answer (score 0):

Distroless images work a bit differently. They expect your CMD to have a form of ["yourfile.jar", "--param1=val1", ...]. Note there is no "java"

You can find this information in the buildfile of distroless java image: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/java/BUILD#L28